# Sqlite: How to speed up those Sqlite queries?

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

Given I have a large table in my local Sqlite database (about 5'000'000 rows) with a schema like this

`id` (integer, unique), e.g. `6543`

`description` (text), e.g. `"any meaningful text"`

`tags` (text), e.g. `"(living)(home)(garden)"`

So if I need to count all entries tagged 'home' and 'garden', I do

`SELECT count(id)
FROM tbl
WHERE tags LIKE ‘%(home)%'
AND tags LIKE '%(garden)%'`

Obviously, this takes like forever.
(I tested it with a 2'000'000 entries table version and it took 93 seconds...)

Would it be wise to introduce new columns, one for each tag (five are max)?

So I'd have columns like

`id | description | tag1 | tag2 | tag3 | tag4 | tag5
34 | blahblah    | home |garden| null | null | null`

The corresponding query would look like

`SELECT count(id)
FROM tbl
WHERE (tag1 = 'home' OR tag2 = 'home' OR tag3 = 'home' OR tag4 = 'home' OR tag5 = 'home')
AND (tag1 = 'garden' OR tag2 = 'garden' OR tag3 = 'garden' OR tag4 = 'garden' OR tag5 = 'garden')`

Is this actually any better?

I just don't have any idea what's best. I'm sure there IS a way to decrease the query time... But I don't know it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Or, maybe, you have a completely new idea how to restructure the data and/or query to make it faster.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to me you are modelling a M-N relation between tags and tbl. You could put these tags in a table: `CREATE TABLE tbl_tags (tbl_id INTEGER REFERENCES tbl(id), tag TEXT)`. Or, if there is a fixed set of tags, put those in a table tags and reference it from tbl_tags. Your second approach, using five "tag" fields, should be much faster than your first approach. If SQLite finds a matching tag, it won't continue evaluating. Are you sure your application won't have more than 5 tags?

Comment: If you create a table for your tags, you could JOIN those: `SELECT count(id) FROM tbl INNER JOIN tbl_tags ON tags.tbl_id = tbl.id AND (tags.tag = 'home' OR ...)`

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you use a condition `...<field> LIKE '%<sub-str>%'` you are triggering a full table scan and hence the long time it takes. Still, for a 2M records with a string (field `tags`) of, say, 64 chars, it appears to me that 93 seconds it way too long a time. I suspect that the issue is not coming from the full scan.

I would suggest you check the time it takes the following query:

```
select count(*)
  from <tablename>
 where tags like '(home)%' ;
```

For the 2M rows, this should not take more than a few seconds. If it does, I would search for performance issues somewhere else.

Additionally, you could store your tags like `|living|home|garder|...` and search for `tags like '%|home|%'` [this will not solve your problem, but you are saving some space since you are replacing `)(` with `|`].

EDIT:

I just realized that you are using two conditions (WHERE ... AND). Try the following:

```
SELECT count(id)
  FROM tbl
 WHERE tags like '%(home)%(garden)%'
    OR tags like '%(garden)%(home)%' ;
```

Comment: Actually, the query you suggested took `359468ms`. Yes, 6 minutes. So obviously the problem seems to be something else. I just do not have any idea what could be wrong. I'm not out of memory, just checked that. There's no other table in the db. What else could I check or do? :(

Comment: Which of the two queries I suggested took 6 mins? If the first (`... where tags like '(home)%'`), then you need to analyze your DB, like monitoring resources while the query executes (CPU, Memory IO, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, the first simple query. I checked the CPU (80% idle) and memory usage (4GB free, only about 200MB used by Sqlite). I just found the PRAGMA settings, increasing the cache_size finally increased the memory usage and therefor reducing the invocation time. First run still takes a while but subsequent queries perform much faster now (about 5 times, approx.). Anyway I still want to improve the table setup so I'll try the tags to table suggestions soon.

Comment: This is extremely strange. See? the `... where tags like '(home)%'` is a by far simpler condition to check when compared to `...'%(home)%'`. My guess is that the query should not take more than, say, 10 secs. There is something wrong with your DB...

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than one instance of the same thing, you should put it into multiple rows.
In this case, this would result in a separate table for the tags:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id INTEGER  REFERENCES tbl(id),
    tag TEXT
);

CREATE INDEX tags_index ON tags(tag);
```

You can then do the query with simple lookups on the `tag` column, which are efficient because of the index:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tbl
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'home')
  AND id IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'garden');
```

Alternatively, use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'home'
      INTERSECT
      SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'garden');
```

Comment: I understand I need a separate `tags`-table with id and tag. I do not understand how this is then linked to the `tbl`-table :( How do I fill the tags-table with each tag in `()`? Is the tag-id a random number or somehow linked to the entry in tbl? I invoked the `create table` & `create index` statements, but obviously the query does not work out of the box because tags-table is empty.. Actually all I know about sql is self-taught and rudimental. I do not know much more than simple select statements. Please advise how to proceed to link the data between the two tables, I'm clueless.

Comment: The `id` refers to the parent table; it is *not* the primary key of the `tags` table.